# Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256 from within node.js web app using firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, jwt, cpanel, firebase-admin

I’m developing a node.js app to send push notifications via the firebase HTTP v1 API, as the older legacy API will be dropped on June 20, 2024.  The code itself is pretty simple - it uses firebase-admin to initialize the admin app and then send the message.  The essence of the code is this:

```
// Note: cpanel invokes app.js via a require statement, forcing app.js to be a CommonJS module. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('firebase-admin/app');
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const jsonBody = require("body/json");
const log4js = require("log4js");
```

...

```
if (setDefaultCredentials(body.app)) { // if service account JSON file found and environment variable set
  
  logger.trace("app.js: input validated... ");

  // prevent multiple initializtions 
  // See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2111
  const alreadyCreatedAps = app.getApps();

  const adminApp = alreadyCreatedAps.length === 0 ?
    admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault() }) :
    alreadyCreatedAps[0];

  logger.trace("app.js: app initialized... ");

  adminApp.messaging().send(body.msg)
  .then((msgrsp) => {  // Response is a message ID string.
    logger.trace("app.js: Successfully sent message:  " + msgrsp);
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/text" });
    response.end(msgrsp);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    logger.error("app.js send error: " + error.toString());
    response.writeHead(500, { "Content-Type": "application/text" });
    response.end("Send error: " + error.toString());
  });
}
```

This code works reliably when run on my local machine.  From my remote server, however, I get the error message

```
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256
```

Here's the code that generates that error, in sign.js within the jsonwebtoken package:

```
  if (header.alg.startsWith('HS') && secretOrPrivateKey.type !== 'secret') {
    return failure(new Error((`secretOrPrivateKey must be a symmetric key when using ${header.alg}`)))
  } else if (/^(?:RS|PS|ES)/.test(header.alg)) {
    if (secretOrPrivateKey.type !== 'private') {
      return failure(new Error((`secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using ${header.alg}`)))
    }
```

The private key is in the unmodified service account JSON file downloaded from firebase.  The remote server is a cpanel-created node.js web application.  I've encountered many different errors while developing this code, mostly 503's.   I have also, on occasion, successfully sent messages using this same key file.  Right now I'm stuck on the asymmetric key error, but I don't think there's anything wrong with the credentials per se.  It's easy to debug locally, but the code works there, and I'm not sure how to debug remotely as I'm limited to the cpanel file manager and SSH terminal.  The `node-modules` folder is a symlink and I can't edit that to insert logging statements.

I'd welcome any insights.

Edit 12/23/2023:

I thought I'd set this aside for a day, and now when I test it, the code runs successfully.  I'm not sure if this is good news or bad, as I need the code to run reliably.  I later added a .htaccess file to prevent caching, thinking that might get in the way of testing fixes.  Upon initial subsequent test, the error recurred, but on the second test it ran successfully again.  I'll continue testing to see if any patterns emerge.

Oh, other details - node version on server is latest available through cpanel: 20.9.0

Edit 01/03/2024:

This fails consistently now with the subject error.  I've listed the current status at this [firebase-admin](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2051) issue.

Edit 01/04/2024:

I elected to take an alternate path and [provide the credentials manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#provide-credentials-manually), but then I got stuck on the error

```
Error: error:02016002:system library:stat:No such file or directory
    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)
```

This caused me to conclude that the cpanel node.js environment itself may be the issue.  I pivoted yet again and deployed the code via Firebase Hosting (with some modifications), and now it seems to work.

I'll close this issue, not because the issue was ever resolved, but because I abandoned the approach that was causing the problem.  My takeaway?  cpanel-based node.js environments may be problematic, especially for Google-intensive code, and using Firebase keeps it (mostly) in the Google family.

Edit 01/05/2024:

I've created the repository [dlcole/httpV1Msg](https://github.com/dlcole/httpV1Msg) as a sample implementation for using a Node.js app on Firebase Hosting to send push notifications via the Firebase HTTP v1 API.